# How do some T-SQL functions know to accept wildcards in their input parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What property of an T-SQL function, like `PATINDEX`, allows it to accept wildcard characters in the pattern parameter? I ask because there are certain functions, such as `LEN`, which do NOT accept wildcards. For example:

```
SELECT LEN('[TML]IME')
SELECT DATALENGTH('[TML]IME')
```

Both return 8, even though any string adhering to such a wildcard sequence would always be 4 characters long. My intuition says that some switch in the internals of the function is forcing the string to be viewed as a literal, but my attempts to find such documentation have failed. What's going on here?

Comment: I think you might be coming from the *nix world where the shell will actually expand the strings before a program is called.  That is not happening here.  What you see is what you get: 8 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are speaking in terms of just the `'[TML]IME'` syntax, then that is merely what the function is doing with it. It is not an issue of the input parameter. PATINDEX handles the very basic, RegEx-like, square brackets because that is what the code of the PATINDEX function does.

The `LEN` and `DATELENGTH` functions do not do anything more than measure the length of whatever string you pass in.

*It should not be assumed that passing a string into a function implies it will be parsed in the same manner as with PATINDEX and the LIKE operator.*

Now, there are some functions which take the `*` wildcard to mean "all fields", such as `CHECKSUM` and `BINARY_CHECKSUM`, and that has to do with the API between T-SQL and the internal functions which I believe are written in C++ and can handle overloads (same function name but different input params), something not allowed in either T-SQL or SQLCLR functions.

Comment: "It should not be assumed that passing a string into a function implies it will be parsed like PATINDEX and the LIKE operator." So, if one did not have access to documentation on which functions did accept patterns, would they have any other means of confirming the behavior other than simply testing it? Asked another way: Are the implementations of these functions documented, or are they a black box to those viewing outside Microsoft?

Comment: @FolksymAndrew: I think it should be assumed that functions would _not_ treat string input params in the quasi-RegEx manner that PATINDEX and LIKE do. Mainly because I think those are the only 2 things that do have that behavior. You can find all T-SQL functions documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I was referring more to the C++ functions you spoke of. It seems unlikely to me that MS would actually release the code they used to implement LEN (or any of their functions), but I would be curious to know a bit more about the internals of these functions

Comment: @FolksymAndrew: No, there is no way we are going to see that code outside of working there ;-). I would be happy enough to just have access to the API that allows me to do overloading via SQLCLR functions :-D.